# How to get item price of the return URL Sandbox PayPal

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I get the following *return URL of SandBox PaylPal*:

> http://mysite.com/success.aspx?tx=9A255742LJ154054X&st=Pending&amt=74.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=Product%201

So it sends the total value `amt=74.00` and not the item price which is `$59.00`.

So my question is how to get the item price?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're including itemized details in the button code you're using.  PayPal provides this list of [standard variables you can use in your buttons](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables), and you may want to refer directly to the [shopping cart section](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HH0D0TA).